# How to create SQL Query using Session Variable?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, flask

I am trying to create a SQL query in a python program and I want to pass in my session variable. The session variable contains the logged in user for the program. I am having some syntax issues.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM following WHERE following.username == 'flask.session['user']' "
```

Here is my error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "user": syntax error
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use Flask so a guess based on common errors: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM following WHERE username = ?", (flask.session['user'],))`

Answer (score 0):

roganjosh fixed the issue.

Use:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM following WHERE username = ?", (flask.session['user'],))
```

Comment: On a high level (i.e. not too specific), do you know what I did there? It's one thing to have working code, it's another to understand why it works so I want to be sure you understand the changes I made.

Comment: This is parameter substitution, right?

Comment: It's a parameterized query which will help against SQL injection. Since you only bind a single variable (which could be a string) you should always supply the value as a tuple (hence `(flask.session['user'],)`) otherwise it will try to unpack your value character-by-character.

Answer (score -1):

If you know that session['user'] is a string, than try this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM following WHERE following.username == '%s' " %(session['user'])
```

You can use, %s for string, %i for integer...

Comment: This is very bad advice; it uses string formatting and leaves the user more exposed to SQL injection. There is no reason at all not to use a parameterized query for this.